# Conditional Substitute in Select PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

My table has `end_date` column as `Date` type

It will have an actual value, a default value or NULL value

- If end date is populated for an employee, it will have actual date
- Default date is `2000-01-01` in yyyy-MM-dd format which is populated
  on 1st of every month
- When a new employee joins in the middle, it has NULL value

I need to make a query which will return the difference in days if it has an actual end date or blank if NULL or default value is there.

```
Select GREATEST(0, DATE_PART('day', end_date::timestamp - CURRENT_DATE))
```

This is the best bet I could manage as of now. Any way of doing it without `If-Else` conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your select-list:

```sql
NULLIF(end_date, '2000-01-01') - CURRENT_DATE
```

The `NULLIF` if will return `NULL`, iff both parameters are the same, and the first parameter otherwise. Subtraction with a `NULL` value (on any side of the operator) will yield `NULL` as well, thus this will give you a "blank" output if `end_date` is not set or is set to the default (if you desire some other special value, surround this "query" with a `COALESCE` and add your default-blank-value as its second parameter). Otherwise you get your desired difference.

I do not see, why there should be any need to cast to `TIMESTAMP`. This will make the subtration to return an `INTERVAL`, but you want an `INTEGER` and this is what you get by subtracting two `DATE`s.

Comment: If end_date is of past, this will give negative value @Islingre

Comment: Well yeah.. what do you need? Perhaps you want to surround with an ```ABS``` or ```GREATEST```. But for me, negative values do make sense

Comment: I need to show 0 if end_date is in past, no of days if it is in future and blank otherwise

Comment: ```(CASE WHEN NULLIF(end_date, '2000-01-01') < CURRENT_DATE THEN 0 ELSE NULLIF(end_date, '2000-01-01') - CURRENT_DATE END```